# Cannot get componentDidMount() to update empty array via this.setState with fetched JSON data

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have an empty array declared as such:

```
class EditPlaylistDetails extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        allPlaylists: []
    }
};
```

And my ComponentDidMount() is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5040/playlist/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.props.sessionToken
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                allPlaylists: res
            },
                () => console.log(this.state.allPlaylists));
        })
};
```

Two problems:
#1) When I try to call upon this fetched data via a .map function, it comes back as "undefined".
#2) The '() => console.log(this.state.allPlaylists))' code snippet doesn't even fire off at all.  It doesn't attempt to execute the console.log.

I am able to console.log(res) within that snippet of code and it displays the updated allPlaylists array with all of the info without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add return to the second promise handler

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch('http://localhost:5040/playlist/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.props.sessionToken
    })
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    }).then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            allPlaylists: res
        },
        () => console.log(this.state.allPlaylists));
    })
```

};

Answer (score 0):

For one of my projects, removing the `{` before `this.setState(` worked.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5040/playlist/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.props.sessionToken
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {console.log(res);})
        .then((res) => this.setState({allPlaylists: res})};
```